# List inbox messages using node.js gmail api

Tags: node.js, gmail, gmail-api

I have done [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) demo, However I am not sure how I would go about listing the actual messages in my inbox. I have looked [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list), but I am not sure how to incorperate that into node?

Thanks in advance! sorry if this is blatantly obvios.

best,
-Zoe

Comment: your question is unclearly to me. What is your requirement?

Comment: I am wondering how to list the context of my inbox similar to the actual gmail website. I am hoping to eventual be able to make a task managing app that shows me the top 10 emails I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow the below steps:

1. make your `node.js` [client](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs).
2. [enable](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) the `push notification`(that notify you when new email arrived).
3. `HistoryId` contains in The notification you received.
4. Get your mailbox [update](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) according `history ID`.
5. Receive history list contain `message Id` , use that message Id and [get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)      the email.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you so much, however when I run the Publisher Guide demo I get this error: node index.js

/home/zoe/Developer/gmailShell/index.js:132
  pubsubClient.createTopic(topicName, (err, topic) => {
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3